Is there an algorithm to solve a question of ratios that balance inputs and outputs?
I have a list of recipes, with fluid inputs and outputs per second:
const waterSeparation = {
  name: 'water separation',
  h2: 20/3,
  o2: 10
};

const ammonia = {
  name: "ammonia",
  h2: -10,
  n2: -10,
  nh3: 10,
}

In this case, every second, one factory running water separation generates 20/3 units of h2 and 10 units of o2, while a factory making ammonia makes 10 nh3 per second while consuming 10 n2 and 10 h2.
const ratios = [{
  recipe: waterSeparation,
  count: 20 // how do I pick these numbers?
}, {
  recipe: ammonia,
  count: 14
} ...]

const results = ratios.reduce((acc, { recipe, count }) => {
  Object.keys(recipe).filter(ingredient => ingredient !== 'name').forEach((ingredient) => {
    if (ingredient in acc){
      acc[ingredient] += recipe[ingredient] * count;
    } else {
      acc[ingredient] = recipe[ingredient] * count;
    }
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

I know how to calculate the current recipes and their excesses/shortages, but I don't know how to pick the right number of each factory. I need an algorithm to balance all the recipes to whole number multiples so that all the outputs are consumed with the lowest whole number of factories running each recipe. I would also be okay if I rounded up to the nearest whole number, in case there is no perfect ratio of each recipe. Is there an algorithm for this?

It sounds like a difficult problem, and probably the best solution is to do a search across possibilities starting from the end-goal and working backwards. Hopefully if you need some ingredient there's 1 or maybe only sometimes 2 possible factories that can produce it. Assuming you're not responsible for actual chemical plants and this is a toy problem, where's the problem from?

You can represent the problem as an integer linear program and solve it with a solver; the variables would be the numbers of each factory, the constraints that the system produces a net positive of each ingredient, and the optimization criteria the sum of the numbers of factories. But that might be overkill depending on the constraints of the problem.

@PaulHankin It's from factorio. I need to know how many chemical plants, atmospheric condensers, electrolysis plants, and fuel refineries i need to turn sand, water, iron plates, and electricity into rocket fuel.
